# How can pwrite protect against overwriting data?

Tags: linux, c, posix

Assume we have two processes A & B. they both want to append to the same file. both opened the file with `open` (without `O_APPEND`) function and they are using `pwrite(fd, buf, bytes, offset)` to write to the file.

how does `pwrite` in this case guarantees that data will not be overwritten since I have to resolve where the end of the file offset is?

Comment: If you just want them both to append to the file, just use `write` instead of `pwrite`.  In that case it is guaranteed that neither will overwrite the other's data.

Comment: If you want to append without worrying about overwriting, just use `O_APPEND`. I don't think `pwrite()` is any different from plain `write()` here, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not guarantee that. End of story, really.

Comment: It sounds like I got the wrong idea from the reason behind this function. the reason I got this idea is because I was reading the APUE book, and the author mentioned that this method was introduced just to solve the issue I am describing (read file I/O chapter if you are interested) but thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marcus Müller wrote:

> It does not guarantee that. End of story, really.

The `pwrite` function alone does not inherently guarantee protection against data overwriting in the scenario you described.

To prevent data overwriting, you would need to implement additional mechanisms, such as file locking, inter-process communication, or coordination through shared data structures, to ensure that the processes do not write to the same offset simultaneously.

Comment: Also note that it is not an error for a successful call to transfer fewer bytes than requested. So your additional mechanism must not merely allow each process to tell the other how much data it tried to write, but how much it actually achieved.